# Parse string using batch script

Tags: command-line, batch, string, parsing

How can I parse string using batch script?

Goal is to save in a array everything under `Import:` and strip out `#head` for example --> `//MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt` and `//Packages/Project/config/cde.txt`.

test.txt:

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt                       #head
   //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt                        #head
View:
  //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
  //Packages/Project/config/de.txt                      #head
```

My try:

```
@echo off

set buildlog="devel.p4inc"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (devel.p4inc) do  (
  if /i "%%A"=="Import:" set "import=true"
  IF DEFINED import (echo %%A)
)
```

desired output

```
   //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt 
   //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt
```

anything under Import:

Comment: For clarity's sake, what's wrong with what you've tried? What results do you get with it (right or wrong)?

Comment: result was wrong.. it is printing everything under Import:.. i would only like //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt and //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt to be printed out..

Comment: Add the result you want to get

Comment: added to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems in your logic is that you set the "import" variable once if something is true, but never reset it, or undefined it if it's not true anymore.  So after the first time it's set, it will remain "defined" for the rest of the loop.

My preference is to set the variable specifically (`true` or `false`).  Set it to `false` to start, then set it to `true` as wanted, but then also ensure you set it back to `false` when you need to.  Then, at each iteration of the loop check if the variable is specifically set to `True` or `False` instead of checking if it's just defined.

This code works for me based on your info/goals:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set buildlog=test.txt
set import=false

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%buildlog%) do (
    if /i "%%A"=="Import:" (
        set import=true
    )
    if /i "%%A"=="View:" (
        set import=false
    )
    if !import!==true (
        if not "%%A"=="Import:" (
            for /F "tokens=1" %%B in ("%%A") do (
                echo %%B
            )
        )
    )
)
```

We purposefully set the "Import" variable (flag) to `false` to start.

First For-loop goes through each line in the file (`test.txt` in this example, as specified by the "buildlog" variable; note: you need to remove the quotes around the file name in the variable for it to work in the For-loop).

The first IF sees if the current line is the "Import:" line, and if so, it flips the "import" flag to `true`.

The next IF sees if the current line is the "View:" line, and if so, it flips the "import" flag (back to) to `false`, so that it stops processing each line.

The 3rd IF checks if that "import" flag is `true`, and if so, it processes the line.

If it's `true` then the nested (4th) IF then checks if the line is the actual "import:" line, and if not, displays the line (keeps it from showing the "Import:" line in the output).

The second For-loop goes through the line we want displayed, and pulls only the first Token set which is (just) the path you want, leaving off the `#head`.

More/related info:

- [Variable Expansion in FOR Loops](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)
- [How to split a string in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file)
- [Logical operators (“and”, “or”) in DOS batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch)

**Edit after comments:**

To deal with the "View:" line if it has a version number after it you could modify the code to something like:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set buildlog=test.txt
set import=false

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%buildlog%) do (
    for /F "tokens=1" %%B in ("%%A") do (
        if /i "%%B"=="Import:" (
            set import=true
        )
        if /i "%%B"=="View:" (
            set import=false
        )
        if !import!==true (
            if not "%%B"=="Import:" (
                for /F "tokens=1" %%C in ("%%A") do (
                    echo %%C
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This added For-loop will pull the first token off the line to check if it's "View:" or "Import:" instead of checking the whole line.  Effectively ignoring anything after the first space it encounters on the line to do the check.

Comment: Damn.. you are great.. nice explanation.. it is removing #head and but it is printing everything View: and things under views..if /i "%%A"=="View:" (
        set import=false
    ) is not working..

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, it works here based on your example data.  Are you sure the line in your actual data is actually just "View:", and there's no extra spaces or anything?  Does the capitalization match etc.? Can you provide a copy of the actual data file you're running it against?

Comment: sorry actually i'm running any application where view is something like "View: 3.2.43"

Comment: Ahh ok, I'll post a modified version that deals with that...

Comment: Thank you TECHIE007 for your help and great explanation...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%A in  ("devel.p4inc") do  (
Set temp=False
if "%%A" == "View:" Goto Exit
if  not "%%A" == "Import:" if  not "%%A" == "Version:"  echo %%A
)
:Exit
```

Comment: Could you explain this as well @kingpin? It would make your answer more helpful to future visitors if you did :) You can [edit] the answer to add a bit of explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

command-line:

```
powershell [string]$f=gc test.txt;$pL=$f.IndexOf('Import:')+7;$pR=$f.IndexOf('View:');$s=$f.Substring($pL,$pR-$pL);$s -split'#head'^|ac result.txt
```

powershell:

```
powershell ./parsefl.ps1
```

parsefl.ps1

```
[string]$f=gc test.txt;
$pL=$f.IndexOf('Import:')+'Import:'.Length;$pR=$f.IndexOf('View:');
$s=$f.Substring($pL,$pR-$pL);
$s -split'#head'|ac result.txt
```